# How to make a PHP Error message popup instead of new page?

Tags: php, html, popup, contacts, contact-form

Currently on my website I have a form in which once it is submitted, you're taken to a blank screen with the appreciation message.

Instead of moving to a new page, I wish to keep my users on the same page. How might I go about creating a popup and keeping the user within the same page?

Comment: You could use JS validation, which makes the popup simple to do.  You'd still need to duplicate the validation logic on the server, though.

Comment: As alternative: use HTML5 form attributes `<input required>` and a Javascript shim to emulate the behaviour in older browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript validation or HTML5.
If you don't want these ways you can just open a popup window and set your form's target to it. Like this :

```
<form method="post" action="anything.php" onsubmit="window.open('','my_form_target', 'width=300,height=200', true); this.target='my_form_target';" >
...
```

Comment: Sweet thank you that did the trick but how to I get it to be a fixed width and height so you can't resize it and have a button in the box in the bottom right corner that says okay and closes the window.

Comment: You can resize your window using javascript. (change window.width and .height in page's load event)
For button concern, place a button at your page and call `close()` function in it's `click`'s event.

Comment: Okay well when the message succeds it has my success message and automatically redirects to home page but it does it in the new window how would I get it to redirect in the original window?

Comment: you can access your main window using `window.opener` in the child window. for example change parent's location this way : `window.opener.location.href = 'somewhere.com';`

Comment: Can you explain a little bit better? Im still kind of new...

Comment: for example instead of redirecting user in normal way, you can use an OK button. put this code on it's click event : `window.opener.location.href='AnyWhere.html';close();`
window.opener refers to the main window (which has opened this popup) and location is it's location...

Comment: Okay can I do it without user input? like with an automatic redirect?

Comment: yep! you can use `setTimeout` function. this function will do anything after a number of milliseconds. here you can find an example : [setTimeout function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: Okay thank you so much for your help but one more question how would I  merge setTimeout with window.opener.location.href='AnyWhere.html';close();

Comment: just pass the code as an string to setTimeout function.
`setTimeout('window.opener.location.href=\'AnyWhere.html\';close();', 3000);`

Answer (score -1):

try this for validation

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        $name = $_POST['uname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        $valid_arr = array();
        $error_arr = array();

            if($name == ''){
                $error_arr['name'] = 'Required';
            }
            else if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-A]+$/',$name)){
                $error_arr['name'] = 'Please put correct value';
            }
            else{
                $valid_arr['name'] = $name;
            }

            if($email == ''){
                    $error_arr['email'] = 'Required';
                }
                else if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4})$/',$email)){
                    $error_arr['email'] = 'Exm.- john@gmail.com';
                }
                else{
                    $valid_arr['email'] = $email;
                }

                if(count($error_arr) == 0){
                    header('location: success.php');
                }
                else{
                    echo 'Error in Loading';
                }
    }
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>User Name :</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="uname" value="<?php echo $valid_arr['name'];?>"/></td>
            <td class="error"><?php echo $error_arr['name'];?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Email :</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $valid_arr['email'];?>"/></td>
            <td class="error"><?php echo $error_arr['email'];?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit"/></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I also recommend a hidden form field to prevent bots submitting the form and then amend the `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')` to something like `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && $_POST['hidden_field'] == 'random_string)`. I use Vaibhav's style of technique with the hidden field and it tends to work well.

Comment: This is not what he's looking for and vulnerable to XSS exploitation.